# Upload/download data from S3 bucket

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, intellij-14

I am trying to upload one file from my local machine however I get the following error:

> AWS Error Code: AccessDenied

Could you please help me how to establish the connection to AWS S3 bucket?

I have used below code for uploading the file.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth._
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client

val bucketName = "bucketname"

val fileToUpload = new File("C:\\text.csv") 
val AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "....."
val AWS_SECRET_KEY = "........."

val yourAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)
val amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(yourAWSCredentials)
// This will create a bucket for storage
//amazonS3Client.createBucket(bucketName)
amazonS3Client.putObject(bucketName, "text.csv", fileToUpload)
```

Comment: Side-note: It is recommend that you _never_ put security credentials (Access Key, Secret Key) in code. Instead, it should be stored in a configuration file. The easiest way to do this is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command.

Comment: Hi John, I have tried CLI also but still having same issue.

Comment: Yes, the credentials you are using do not have permission to upload to that bucket. The same credentials are used via the API or the CLI. You should speak to your administrators and request permissions necessary for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `access denied` error so your code tries to connect to S3 correctly. The issue, at this moment, is not in your code and it is in your security clearance.

So in AWS, you should go to IAM and check the security policies related to your `access` and `secret` key and see why you can not access to your S3.

Comment: once you get valid credentials, you can also have a look at [Benji](https://zengularity.github.io/benji/) DSL for S3